# UIButton not clickable outside initial frame of an UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I got stuck with the strange behavior of UIScrollView that I cannot click on the UIButton after I enlarge the contentSize of the UIScrollView.

What I wanted to do:

1. **Show a form with using UIScrollView**
2. **After clicking on the submit button, the scroll view will enlarge some amount of height to show further information.**
3. **In the further information, I will place and show another UIButton(hidden at the beginning) in order to process to the next step.**

The problem is that I placed the new UIButton to the enlarged area and the button is not clickable whereas I placed the UIButton to existing area(the initial frame of scroll view) then the button works normally. For both cases, the scroll bar of the scroll view performs normal behavior.(ie, the scroll end is the new content height)

Here is what I have so far:

- A UIView xib (placed all elements inside it including the hidden button)
- A UIScrollView (loaded the UIView xib into it)

`UIView* view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"view" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];`

`[view loaded];`

`[scrollView addSubview:view];`

- After the submit button is clicked:

`// offset = some amount;`

`[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollview.contentSize.width, scrollview.contentSize.height+offset)];`

`// h = some amount before the end of the scroll view`

`CGRect r = nextBtn.frame;`

`r.origin.y = h;`

`nextBtn.frame = r;`

`[nextBtn setHidden:NO];`

[image]

I have tried to change the clipSubviews attribute of scroll view but seems it is not working for my case at all.

Anyone knows how it happens? And is there any better methods to get this job done? (resize the scroll view and then place another button in it)

Any help would be great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: how about set `button.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x,scrollView.contentSize.height - button.frame.size.height,button.frame.size.width,button.frame.size.height)` and see if button place at the end of the scrollView.

Comment: the button appears at the end of the scrollView but still not clickable. It seems that the area below the initial frame is not clickable...

Comment: Hey user3088152, did you find any solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume that the button is direct or indirect child of the contents view you load from the xib file.

The problem is because you changed the scroll view's `contentSize` but did not change the frame of the contents view. Superviews participate in touch hit testing. You can place a subview outside of its superview bounds and by default the subview will not be clipped but touch events will not be delivered to it because the superview checks during hit testing that the touch is outside of its bounds and rejects the touch. See `UIView` `hitTest:withEvent:` for details.

Comment: Exactly! I just updated the contentSize of the scroll view but the frame of my UIView remains the initial frame. It works if I also update the frame of the UIView! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I am facing same issue. I have two separate XIBs to load and views from xib are added in scrollview. Touch/click event is not working for the last view which is added last and not in visible area. How to update frame of view after adding to scrollview?

Comment: @yurish thx for superb answer. ha ha.. What i mean was, how exactly we can decide which view need frame change according to visible/non visible to scrollview. Lets say i have two view each from separate XIB. Initially second view's y position is decide by first view's Y + first view's height. Second view is not visible initially but as an when i scrolldown i can see view is placed properly but none of the buttons/links are clickable of that second view. Now how to update frame of buttons/links of that second view?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing you code. How do you add views from XIBs to the scroll view? Do you have one parent view that is subview of the scroll view and you add XIB views to that parent view? If yes - you need to update the frame of the parent view so that it includes the second view. If you add both XIB's views separately as subviews of the scrollview and contentSize is properly set then the problem may be elsewhere.

Answer (score -2):

You can add a button say submit and another button as subview of the scrollview.Keep your another button hidden in start and call setContentsize. now when user clicks on submit button then set another button to visible and again call set content size.In this way you would be able to achieve what you want to.

i have tried to generate scenario for you.I have tried this on view based application with storyboard without auto layout.

so in story board do some thing like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

@interface ALViewController : UIViewController

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
```

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;

===========
implementation:

```
#import "ALViewController.h"
```

@interface ALViewController ()

@end

@implementation ALViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{
     [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.btn2 setHidden:YES];

```
[self adjustContentSize];
```

}

-(void)adjustContentSize
{
    CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
    for (UIView *view in self.scroll.subviews)
    {
        if (![view isHidden]) {
            contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
        }
    }

```
self.scroll.contentSize = contentRect.size;
```

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (btn.tag ==1)
    {
        [self.btn2 setHidden:FALSE];
        [self adjustContentSize];
    }

```
}
```

@end

and in storyboard some thing like this:

[image]
@end

for your information:view frame 0,0,768,1024
scroll frame: 0,0,768,1024
btn1 frame: 361, 753, 46, 30
btn2 frame: 351, 1032, 46, 30

run your code :
at first your scroll view would be unscrollable because we have set btw 2 to be hidden and set content size.As soon as you will be clicking on btn 1, see code we are making btn 2 visible again and calling set content size.

Conclusion:

**the scrollview content size looks for its visible contain of which we can take benefit of.**

thanks and regards.