# UIButton in scrollView unresponsive when outside initial frame

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton, xib

I have a very long view (>2000 pixels) created in a xib. This xib is loaded and then, inside it's ViewController I switch the root view for a scroll view (I want that 2000 pixels to scroll);

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *view = self.view;

    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    scroll.contentSize = self.view.bounds.size;

    self.view = scroll;
    [scroll addSubview:view];
}
```

The long view has a button but it does not fire if it's placed outside the top of the long view (i.e. outside the initial screen frame).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607610/uibutton-not-clickable-outside-initial-frame-of-an-uiscrollview) seems similar but is slightly different as that SO user is extending the size of the scroll view dynamically. In this case, the scroll view of fixed size (full screen) but I can't hit things in my xib that are outside of the initial frame. During debug, I can see the frame of both the scroll view and content view are set (and long)...

```
<UIView: 0x946db50; frame = (0 0; 320 2320); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x946db20>>

<UIScrollView: 0x9077e10; frame = (0 0; 320 2320); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xb388bd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x9276f60>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

How can I ensure that taps are making it to controls scrolled into view?

Comment: check for my updated solution for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

this will create a scrollView to the match the actual view of view Controller then

```
 UIView *newView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,2320)];

[scrollView addSubview:newView];
```

//u can also create this view from your long view in story board, never use the self.view inside scroll this make Ur hierarchy critical add on more long view inside the controller then refer that view to new instance in view-controller then use here

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, newview.frame.size.height);
```

then set

> **OLD answer**

Set contentsize property of ur scroll view to macth the height of ur scroll view and width of your view inside scroll view...

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error I fixed this, but I'm not sure why it works. In the code above, I init the UIScrollView to have the same size frame as the content view (which actually doesn't make sense, not sure why it scrolls at all).

Instead, I got it working to sizing to the screen (since it will be full screen):

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
```

And now it all works swimmingly. Odd; would love to understand why this is.